# How play this rook end game

Tags: rook-endgame

In the video Can 3 Women Beat A Grandmaster?

https://youtu.be/umCJkXuow9I?si=a-aHT-SrbNdcgJU_&t=1071

- White: Dina Belenkaya
- Black: Danya Naroditsky

Engine show white are winning, but the thing was Dina didn't know how to play it and Danya on the other hand did know.

I can see black was countering every white move, so I guess there is a sequence of move for white to allow gain a tempo and allow them to move the points.

White just move the rook.
So curious what those move sequence will be.

[image]

Comment: I struggle to win this as white against engines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White's best moves depend on what moves Black plays, of course, but it could go something like this:

```
[FEN "8/3R1K1k/2r4P/6P1/8/8/8/8 b - - 0 1"]

1... Rg6 2. Rd5 Ra6 3. Rd1 Ra7+ 4. Kf6 {The only winning move here!} (4. Ke6?? Kg6 {This is drawn.}) Ra6+ 5. Ke5 (5... Kg6 6. Rd6+) Ra5+ 6. Rd5 Ra6 7. Rd6 Ra5+ 8. Kf6 Ra7 9. Re6 Ra1 (9... Rb7 10. Re7+)  (9... Ra8 10. Re7+ Kh8 11. g6 {White is now threatening mate if Black's rook leaves the bank rank without check.} Rf8+ 12. Kg5 Ra8 13. Re5 Rg8 14. Rd5 Rb8 15. h7 Kg7 16. Rd7+ Kh8 17. Kh6 {Threatens g7#} Rg8 18. hxg8=Q+ Kxg8 19. Rd8#) 10. Re7+ Kg8 11. Re8+ Kh7 12. g6+ Kxh6 13. Rh8#
```